# Determine current build type / scheme in macro

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to be able to block Archive builds (for distribution) via a macro, so that I don't forget to add or change critical functionality.

Ideally, I want to do:

```
#define REQUIRE_FIX(ERROR_MSG) (\
#if __ \
#error ERROR_MSG \
#endif)
```

What do I need to put for `__` to check the current build type / scheme?

Comment: I do that usually via DEFINE that are set within the built configuraton - similar to the DEBUG define that is automatically set when building with a debug-configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set preprocessor defines for each build scheme in build options of your target.

[image]

Normally to block an Archive build I will just use

```
#ifndef DEBUG
    #error "Fix this first!"
#endif
```